# handle social networks authentication with own API backend

Tags: rest, authentication, oauth, social-networking, backend

How can I handle authentication via OAuth for some social networks in my own backend?

My first approach with facebook was

1. Authenticate the client directly with facebook and get the accessToken
2. Send the accessToken to my own backend and create a new user, getting the details from opengraph
3. Return from the backend to the client an ApiKey (Own authentication), what is needed in each call to my backend

My questions are:

This approach is right? Maybe this works with facebook, but with twitter how can I get an "accessToken" and getting the data user like the opengraph from facebook? And, if I need anothers social network, this works?

Comment: Did you check if this part of the protocol was the same in OAuth 1.0a and 2.0? If Wikipedia is right, [Twitter and Facebook don't implement the same version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth#List_of_OAuth_service_providers).

Answer (score 0):

I believe your approach is correct as OAuth2.0 by standards doesn't let a user LOGIN. Instead, you can get an access_token on their approval of your application to access their data, create the user on your side and that's it. Basically, you are going to use their social data to speed up the "sign-up" (and even possibly the sign-in process provided you assume that the authentication will be done through social networks) for the user.

In terms of how generic you want your implementation to be such that it will work with all social networks, I recommend you look into [Spring Social](http://projects.spring.io/spring-social/) as it already does a lot of that kind of work for you (in case you want it to be extremely generic).

Hope that helps!